# Jmeter - Kibana syncronization (logs testing)

Tags: jmeter, kibana

Is exists way to connect Jmeter to Kibana (Log management tool).
I want to check scenario that after the system received an HTTP requests,  it send postback to other system.
it is not a response but another process, Is this scenario can be tested via Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by adding  [Elasticsearch Backend Listener](https://github.com/delirius325/JMeter_ElasticsearchBackendListener) plugin you can setup to connect JMeter results to be shown in `Kibana` dashboard, see [full article](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/04/06/load-testing-with-jmeter-test-results-visualization-using-kibana-dashboards/).

Comment: The postback is not sent by Jmeter, it is another process, I want to Jmeter search in Kibana regardless the request or the response. for example like it connect to DB, it can pull data regardless any process in Jmeter. So Can I search in kibana a string via Jmeter without any http request or response